# RecyclerView moves to top on adding new items to List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement an endless scroll using recycler but when I call notifyDataSetChanged() the whole list refreshes then the scroll position goes back to the top.So I went through many docs mentioned for the same.I am scrolling from top to bottom like in any chatting application.

So i check if layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0,then i download more items.
At a time only 30 iems are downloaded.I dont want my list to move to top,it should stay where it was.

I tried using notifyItemRangeInserted(position,size),this gives some animation which i dont want.I want the scroll to be smooth and hassle free.Also this also dont maintain the position.How to acheive the same

Comment: use notifyitemInserted and also use recyclerview.scrolltoposition(yourList.size() -1);

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @Divyesh i dont want it to scroll to that position,it will be noticeable.I dont want it to scroll at all.

Comment: but scroll is not noticable, i am currently using this and it is working good

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,Worked for me.
you can save the position in a variable.

[scrollToPositionWithOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

I have earlier implemented something like this.
May It can help you, feel free to ask.

```
productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, products, productsListView);
        productsListView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
            productAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListner() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                products.add(null); // here products is an array list of produt
                productAdapter.notifyItemInserted(products.size() - 1);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        products.remove(products.size() - 1);
                        productAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(products.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        long lastItemId = products.get(products.size() - 1).getId();
                        ArrayList<Product> newProductList = new ArrayList<>(); //download or fetch new data (Some more Products) and assign it newProductList

                        products.addAll(products.size(), newProductList.getProducts());
                        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        productAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 2000);

            }
        });
    }
```